# Get Ancestor by class name

Tags: javascript, html, google-closure-library

I have a component which have buttons and list both of which perform events on click. I need a common way to get the ancestor element for these elements. The structure looks like

```
<div class='a'>
   <button class ='b' data-name="hello">
      <span class ='c'>clickMe
         <span>somehting</span>
      </span>
   <button>
   <ul class ='d'>
      <li data-name="about">
          <span class ='e'>something here
             <span>somehting</span>
          </span>
      </li>
      <li data-name="home">
          <span class ='e'>something elser here
              <span>somehting</span>
          </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I try to get the element button and li because I need to get data-name information. 
e.target is the element that was clicked

```
var targetel = goog.dom.getAncestorByClass(e.target,null,class??);
```

Not sure how to get the correct element irrespective if its a button or li. Do i need to add a unique class to all the elements ?

Comment: if the clicked element is always the immediate descendant of the element containing the name data, can't you just use `e.target.parentNode`?

Comment: actually thats not the case the span element can have addtional span child elements. To be more specific I have edited the problem. However the only solution i can think of its to give each element some class name

Comment: Sadly (although some would argue that it's a good thing because of performance issues) There is no way to get parent elements using a css selector

https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/


that being said. Let me make sure i understand you.  So you click either one of the span.e elements and you need to get the parent li element (which is not always the direct parent) and also the data-name information from button.b ?

Comment: ah so lets say you click on span element within one of the li element then you should get the data-name of that li element. similarly if you click on the span element within the button you should get data-name of the button.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `e.currentTarget`

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var clickables = document.querySelectorAll('button, li');

//add click listener to elements
for (var i = 0, l = clickables.length; i < l; i++) {
  clickables[i].addEventListener('click', getDataName);
}

function getDataName(e) {
  var dataName = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-name');
  
  result.textContent = dataName;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
   <button class ='b' data-name="hello">
      <span class ='c'>clickMe
         <span>somehting</span>
      </span>
   </button>
   <ul class ='d'>
      <li data-name="about">
          <span class ='e'>something here
             <span>somehting</span>
          </span>
      </li>
      <li data-name="home">
          <span class ='e'>something elser here
              <span>somehting</span>
          </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="result">data-name of clicked element goes here</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Use the jquery.parents("li") function. it will select all the parents that match your css filter.  so you can do

`var parentli =   targete1.parents("li");`

```
var button = targete1.parents("div").children[0];
```

Or something similar to that.

EDIT: 
Not sure why i got downvoted, here is my idea in action.

maybe press f12 to inspect element and look at the console log.

```js
var onClick = function () {
    var parentEl = $(this).parents("button, li")[0];
    console.log(parentEl);
    $("#result")[0].innerText = parentEl.getAttribute("data-name");
};

$('span.c').click(onClick);

$('li span.e').click(onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>
   <button class='b' data-name="hello">
      <span class='c'>clickMe
         <span>something</span>
      </span>
    </button>
   <ul class ='d'>
      <li data-name="about">
          <span class ='e'>something here
             <span>somehting</span>
          </span>
      </li>
      <li data-name="home">
          <span class ='e'>something elser here
              <span>something</span>
          </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="result">result goes here</div>
```

Comment: You probably got the downvote because the OP is not tagged as JQuery.
Also, .closest() is usually a better choice than .parents()